# How to hide sensitive data from pipeline for sh commands

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have `Jenkinsfile` that creates `mt` object and passes `vaultToken` to psl library:

Jenkinsfile:

```
@Library('shared-library@psl')
Maintenance mt = new Maintenance()
mt.setVaultToken(config.vaultToken)
mt.setApiUrl(config.apiUrl)
pslService.createMaintenance(mt)
```

pslService:

```
String createMaintenance(Maintenance mt){
   dockerBuildHelper.getDockerImage(dockerBuildHelper.getWdBuildDockerImageName()).inside('-u root'){
      String cmd = "curl -X POST '${mt.getApiUrl()}'" +
             " -H 'Content-Type: application/json'" +
             " -H 'Authorization: Api-Token ${mt.getVaultToken()}'" +
             " -d ${mt.getPayload()} | jq -r '.id'"
      return sh(script: cmd, returnStdout: true).trim()
   }
}
```

But this prints curl command and exposes vault token in the pipeline.

Does anyone know how I can hide the sensitive info and/or entire curl command?
I do not want to store this in credentials store, unless I have no choice.

I heard I can use `set +x`. But I am not sure how to use it and if it helps. Any thoughts?

Comment: what if you specify "-s" flag to make curl silent i.e. curl -s ...

Comment: @PankajSaini that didn't help. It was still showing the entire curl command. Thanks for your input anyways

Comment: return sh(script: """
                    set +x
                    curl -X POST '${mt.getApiUrl()}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Api-Token ${mt.getVaultToken()}' -d ${mt.getPayload()} | jq -r '.id'
                """, returnStdout: true).trim()

Comment: You can try this """ is for multi-line, the set +x needs o to be in a separate line

Answer (score 0):

Try to use mask password plugin. Or create secrets in jenkins and call them in environment block of pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I went with `set +x`

```
String cmd = """set +x
          curl -X POST '${mt.getApiUrl()}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Api-Token ${mt.getVaultToken()}' -d ${mt.getPayload()} | jq -r '.id'
       """
return sh(script: cmd, returnStdout: true).trim()
```